# Adobe Air: Start native window hidden

Tags: windows, apache-flex, flex4, air

How do I open a new window as hidden? (note the `visible="false"`)

```
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
      showStatusBar="false"
      resizable="false" 
      visible="false">
```

If I declare a window this way, and then call `this.open(false);`, the window will quickly open and then hide, and then be reshown when I actually display it, which is quite ugly.

I want to do this to be able to load content and fit the window to that size before showing it.

Comment: That just makes the contents invisible. This is a native window.

Comment: I was able to get this working (with a WindowedApplication), when I started a rewrite using the Parsley framework.  However, I this was at a coop job(internship) which I have recently completed, so I no longer have access to the code.

I didn't solve the original problem, which was solely working with a Window.

I plan on not using Air or any Flash based products for my personal projects, so I don't think I'll be returning to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to set my application invisible (visible=false) in the preinitialize event handler of the application and set it to visible in the handleOnInvoke event handler.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Using AIR 3.6. The visible tag is false in app descriptor file.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use systemChrome, you can set initial and minimal size to zero, otherwise system header will be visible. SystemChrome also prohibits use of transparency, so I see no way to make hidden window with it.

Comment: How can that be? It worked in Flex3. Following scenario: I set visible to false in my AIR descriptor file so that the native window is invisible initially. Then in my app setup I recall window size and position from a Flash/AIR local shared object and set those values to my window and AFTER THAT I make the window visible by calling nativeWindow.activate().

However setting visible to false in AIR descriptor file seems to have no effect since Flex 4. It just always makes the window visible, no matter I set it to false.

Any ideas about that?

Comment: This setting only makes window visible as soon as it is created, this confuses me too. I haven't found clear way to make window hidden by default, so resize to zero size is best I can get.

Comment: I was using system chrome, and wanted to leave it that way.